# Prefix key `C-S-c` is echoed as `C-c`

Tags: emacs

When I press `C-S-c`, the echo area shows only `C-c`. Things like `C-S-` selection do work, however.

I'm in Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn in case this helps.

Here's the code for the key binding (for multiple cursors) in my `.emacs`:

```
;; multiple cursors
(require 'multiple-cursors)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c C-S-c") 'mc/edit-lines)
```

Comment: Is `C-S-c` defined as a prefix key; i.e., is it bound to a keymap? When do you see `C-c` in the minibuffer - is it when you use the first `C-S-c`, in preparation for using it a second time?

Comment: For future reference: S is not Space. It is Shift+s. So C-S-c is "ctrl+shift+s+c"

Answer (score 1):

Is `C-S-c` defined as a *prefix key*; i.e., is it bound to a keymap? When do you see `C-c` in the minibuffer -- is it when you use the first `C-S-c`, in preparation for using it a second time?

The following works for me.  If something similar doesn't work for you, consider filing a bug report, providing a step-by-step recipe: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

```
(define-prefix-command 'foo)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c") 'foo)
(define-key foo (kbd "C-S-c") 'open-line)
```

Then pressing `C-S-c` shows `C-S-c` in the minibuffer (actually, in the echo area), while waiting for another key.  If I then press `C-s-c` again, command `open-line` is invoked.